# Relative Identity vs Set Theory

Tags: model-theory, equivalence-relations

The last complete, but unpublished, paper by the late Tom Etter titled "[Three-Place Identity](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510223843/http://www.boundaryinstitute.org/bi/articles/Three-place_Identity.pdf)" purports to prove that all of mathematics can be expressed in terms of relative identity.  In his own words from the abstract:

> In this paper it will be shown that all of mathematics can be
>   expressed in terms of relative identity when this concept is
>   formalized as a three-place predicate.  My focus here will be on the
>   proof of this theorem, though I'll also take a brief look at how
>   three-place identity might help to expand the horizons of science,
>   which is the main topic of [a longer paper, Membership and Identity](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925072222/http://www.boundaryinstitute.org/bi/articles/Membership_&_Identity.pdf).

He proceeds to do so by proving relative identity can express set theory.

Unfortunately, Etter was to pass away before completing the longer paper.

Is this result already known to mathematics -- perhaps under another name?  If not, is the result is incorrect?  If correct and not previously known, does it have broad implications, including for the philosophy of science?

Comment: Is he basically saying that, while ZFC is usually written in terms of membership (i.e. $x\in y$ where $\in$ is an irreflexive relation), it can just as easily be written in terms of relative identity (i.e. $x(y=z)$ where $=$ is an equivalence relation)? That's interesting.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I think what he's saying is that while the axioms of ZFC are usually written using the symbol $\in$, they could also be written using the symbol $=$. It would be the same axioms, but now we're thinking in terms of relative identity rather than membership.

Comment: Oh, ok. I *was* missing a crucial fact, then. Thank you, @columbus8myhw

Comment: Oh... I see in what terms you deemed it interesting: in a sense, any set establishes an equivalence relation on the class of sets having exactly $2$ equivalence classes. Question is: do we really need that number to be $2$? @columbus8myhw

Comment: Wait. Doesn't his way of translating ZFC into identity-language imply $x(a\ne b)\land x(b\ne c)\implies x(a=c)$? I'm not sure if this is intentional. Although, I suppose there are possibly other ways of describing ZFC in terms of relative identity. EDIT: @G.Sassatelli Didn't see your comment.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I'm guessing that Etter would prefer to found mathematics differently than the way he's described here. ("The way he's described here" being the translation between $\in$ and $=$.) The purpose of that was only to show that it's _possible_ to base mathematics in terms of relative identity. But if he were to write a sequel paper showing you how to define various mathematical objects in terms of relative identity — like how traditional set theory shows you how to define stuff in terms of sets — then I think would probably do it with more than 2 equivalence classes.

Comment: I suppose that now we have to figure out just how to do that. How would you define natural numbers in terms of relative identity? Would it be similar to Von Neumann's set-theory definition, or is something else more convenient?

Comment: I hesitate to introduce it here, but in late 2012 I was, with the help of his home care nurse, able to scan a copy of Etter's unfinished paper Membership and Identity when it became apparent that he would never finish it due to loss of mental capacity (which had set in some years earlier with his beloved wife's death) and declining health.  As it is unfinished it may have serious problems and should therefore not be taken as representative of his work.   http://www.boundaryinstitute.org/bi/articles/Membership_&_Identity.pdf

Comment: Etter's earlier paper, explicitly addressing relation numbers and arithmetic, that led to his relative identity theory was Relation Arithmetic Revived.  I think it an adequate rejoinder to G Solomon's  ‎1989 paper "What Became of Russell's 'Relation Arithmetic'" in which Solomon seems to write Relation Arithmetic off as subsumed by model theory.  Etter does explicitly address model theory in Membership and Identity.  http://www.boundary.org/bi/articles/Relation-arithmetic_Revived_v3.pdf

Comment: The two prior links are now dead but archived as: https://web.archive.org/web/20130511044419/http://www.boundaryinstitute.org/bi/articles/Membership_&_Identity.pdf and https://web.archive.org/web/20130511001230/http://www.boundaryinstitute.org/bi/articles/Relation-arithmetic_Revived_v3.pdf